# Laravel Nginx overriding phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, phpmyadmin, routes

I am having a weird issue where Laravels routing system is overriding my phpMyAdmin. When I first setup the server my nginx setup for phpMyAdmin worked perfectly, then after installing Laravel the only thing I changed in my nginx config was the root. and now instead of going to phpmyadmin it is going to "whoops something went wrong" in laravel, which is laravel saying there is no route for that page. Any idea on how to force nginx to not use laravel for that URL? here is my current config.
[image]

Comment: How do you know that "whoops something went wrong!" Means laravel saying there is no route?

Comment: I use laravel everyday on LAMP stack. If you turn on debugging it says the equivalent of 404 on this page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** to bring attention to [Xavier Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1164809/xavier-lucas)' correction:

The `~ \.php$` location is taking precedence because it is a regular expression. Add `^~` to the top-level `/phpmyadmin` location (making it a regex location as well) allowing it to take precedence if matched.

```
location ^~ /phpmyadmin {
  ...
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  ...
}
```

---

The `~ \.php$` location block is handling requests ending in ".php" before they reach `/phpmyadmin`.

Try reversing the two blocks:

```
location /phpmyadmin {
  ...
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  ...
}
```

Comment: @CalvinMoss I'll update my answer, but first: you ran `service nginx reload` to load this new configuration after changing the file, right?

Comment: Yes I did the restart command and then stop and start after that to see if that would make a difference. :/

Comment: A few points to correct : a simple swap of the locations won't help as the precedence taken by the php location is due to it's nature :  regex locations take precendence over prefixed locations. Use `^~` operator to make prefixed location a higher priority after swapping these two blocks. It's necessary for nested locations to declare the prefix of the parent location or nginx will think it's outside of the scope and raise an error, so his phpmyadmin locations are perfectly legit.

Comment: This also did not work :( Do you think it might have to do with capitalization? all the references in my nginx are phpmyadmin but the URL is phpMyAdmin and so is the directory.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being the name of my folder was phpMyAdmin and the nginx config was phpmyadmin so it was not working. However! I would have ran into the same issue that was answered by wolfemm